# Facebook pages longer than 700px without scrollbars

Tags: php, html, facebook

How do you get a Facebook page using the iframe to be longer than 700px without scrollbars to appear without cropping at 700px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Facebook is not always resizing correct so I usually use in my applications an Array witch is called after page load or after i make some changes to the size:

```
FB.Array.forEach([0, 100, 300, 500, 1000, 2000], function(delay) {
            setTimeout(function() { FB.Arbiter.inform("setSize", FB.Canvas._computeContentSize()) }, delay)
})
```

and

```
FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
```

they always worked for me

Answer (score 2):

There is a javascript call in their API to resize the iFrame.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/

Answer (score 0):

I think it isn'T achievable if they don't have such option there.

Comment: it seems to be possible as other people seem to have done it see http://www.facebook.com/pages/Mughli-Restaurant-Charcoal-Pit/159668590714632

Comment: no just html and css i think i might have resolved the issue see this link:http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=190322544333196&topic=5632

Answer (score 0):

Impossible facebook iframe are set by their side not yours. Max width is 700px but you can have higher heights ...